# Halachic considerations in leaving a cash tip in a restaurant?

Tags: halacha, restaurant

Waiters like cash tips because they do not report the tips to the IRS and so keep all of the money.  (Perhaps not all waiters, but the majority, per some web sites.)  Tips put on a credit card are easier for the IRS to track.

I would like to make the waiters happy in this regard (esp since they are paid such low hourly wages, less than the usual minimum) but is there halacha that I should be considering?

Does it make a difference if I pay the restaurant bill with a credit card and leave the tip in cash versus paying both in cash?  (I prefer to pay with credit card to get the points.)

Does it matter if the waiter is Jewish or not?

Comment: You are not causing the waiter to avoid taxes. As far as you know the waiter is paying taxes on the tips. In fact, the IRS often assumes a certain amount of tips based on the salary or working hours at a restaurant and will expect it to be declared. not declaring tips can trigger an audit.

Comment: Is paying cash in any sales context necessarily a michshol?

Comment: @sabbahillel I am not causing the water to violate the law of the land, but I am providing a temptation (an avoidable temptation).  Is providing a temptation the same as aiding and abetting, or at least enabling and perhaps encouraging?

Comment: @Danno  An accountant once said that if all cash transactions were replaced by credit cards, there would be much less crime. The would be little or no fencing of stolen property or buying/selling of illegal drugs, for example. So perhaps, Yes, any cash dealing raises the issue of michshol.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate what you think the halachic problem might be. _Lifne iver_ of _gezel_? Handling cash, [which has a face on it](/q/33965)? Violation of _dina d'malchusa_ of aiding tax evasion? Maybe more than one of the above?

Comment: @msh210  Yes.  I was seeking suggestions as to what the halachic issues might be. If I knew what the various issues are, I would not need to ask the question.  The suggestions in your comment include one I had not thought of.

Comment: What about לא תחנם?

Comment: @ZevSpitz.  Perhaps that, too (Lo Techanem, Devarim 7:2).

Comment: I think לא תחנם applies only to non-Jews and/or idolaters. If you want answers so restricted, then you presumably also want answers restricted in other directions, like Jose that discuss the prohibition of handling money on the sabbath or of paying with stolen money or…. The answers are virtually endless then.

Comment: @msh210   Sometimes seemingly simple questions require long halachic answers. Perhaps that is the case with the question I asked.  (BTW, I have seen Lo Techanem  restricted to land.)